# Is the following a typo or am I understanding wrongly regarding discriminator?

Tags: papers, generative-adversarial-networks

Consider the following paragraph from the `section 3: Background` of the research paper titled [Generative Adversarial Text to Image Synthesis](https://proceedings.mlr.press/v48/reed16.pdf) by Scott Reed et al.

> Goodfellow et al. (2014) prove that this minimax game has a global
> optimium precisely when $p_g = p_{data}$, and that under mild
> conditions (e.g. G and D have enough capacity) $p_g$ converges to
> $p_{data}$. In practice, in the start of training samples **from D** are
> extremely poor and rejected by D with high confidence. It has been
> found to work better in practice for the generator to maximize
> $\log(D(G(z)))$ instead of minimizing $\log(1 −D(G(z)))$

I am guessing the bolded portion should be replaced by  **from G**. Am I correct? If not, where am I going wrong?

Comment: I think it's a typo (but given that I am not an expert in GANs, I will let someone else provide a formal answer). There's another (less severe) typo in that same paragraph, i.e. "optimium", it should have been "optimum". Not sure why this kind of typo goes through the scrutiny of the reviewers or even automatic correction software (like Grammarly or even the editor(s) they used to write the paper).